# turn off/exclude routes in Kohana, for example my gallery/ dir

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Im trying to access galleries/2/image.jpg, but Kohana thinks its a route so it return an error "Unable to find URI route galleries"

So how can i turn off for specific directory/route names, so i can access the images?

Comment: Are you using kohana 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2 by the way?

Comment: If your `.htaccess` is set up correctly to serve files without processing the URL and this still occurs, your URL is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess should look something like this

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^!galleries/.*$
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

that should exclude it from being sent to the routing engine.

Comment: try again with the line I just added above the final rewrite rule. That says to route to index so long as the request URI does not contain the word galleries.